# what is the purpose of passing -1 in add function?

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication, strassen

I am currently programming a Strassen multiplication program in CPP using vectors. I just want to know why at some function add -1 are passed and at some add function call, -1 is not passed. what is the use purpose of passing -1 in function? if I remove that -1 from the calls I got a different incorrect output.

```
// Strassen’s Matrix Multiplication
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// Size of two matrices
#define ROW_1 4
#define COL_1 4
#define ROW_2 4
#define COL_2 4

// print the matrix
void print(vector<vector<int> > matrix) {
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix[i].size(); j++){
            cout << matrix[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

// Add two matrices and return the result
vector<vector<int>> add(vector<vector<int> > A, vector<vector<int> > B, int split_index, int multiplier = 1) {
    for (auto i = 0; i < split_index; i++)
        for (auto j = 0; j < split_index; j++)
            A[i][j] = A[i][j] + (multiplier * B[i][j]);
    return A;
}

vector<vector<int>> strassen_multiplication(vector<vector<int> > A, vector<vector<int> > B) {

    // calculating the size of matrix
  int row_1 = A.size();
    int col_1 = A[0].size();
    int row_2 = B.size();
    int col_2 = B[0].size();

    // checking if multiplication is possible or not
    // between the input matrices
    if (col_1 != row_2) {
        cout << "The Two Matrices cannot be multiplied";
        return {};
    }

    // creating an empty matrix to store the result
    vector<int> result_row(col_2, 0);
    vector<vector<int> > result(row_1, result_row);

    // Base case
    // if size of matrix is 1
    if (col_1 == 1)
        result[0][0]
            = A[0][0] * B[0][0];
    else {

        // split index
        int split_index = col_1 / 2;

        vector<int> row_vector(split_index, 0);

        // Splitting the matrices in sub matrices
        vector<vector<int> > a00(split_index, row_vector);
        vector<vector<int> > a01(split_index, row_vector);
        vector<vector<int> > a10(split_index, row_vector);
        vector<vector<int> > a11(split_index, row_vector);
        vector<vector<int> > b00(split_index, row_vector);
        vector<vector<int> > b01(split_index, row_vector);
        vector<vector<int> > b10(split_index, row_vector);
        vector<vector<int> > b11(split_index, row_vector);

        // calculating and storing the result
        // inside our quadrants
        for (auto i = 0; i < split_index; i++)
            for (auto j = 0; j < split_index; j++) {
                a00[i][j] = A[i][j];
                a01[i][j] = A[i][j + split_index];
                a10[i][j] = A[split_index + i][j];
                a11[i][j] = A[i + split_index]
                                    [j + split_index];
                b00[i][j] = B[i][j];
                b01[i][j] = B[i][j + split_index];
                b10[i][j] = B[split_index + i][j];
                b11[i][j] = B[i + split_index]
                                    [j + split_index];
            }

        // Calculating the multiplication using the formula
        // given by strassent algorithm
        vector<vector<int>> p1(strassen_multiplication(a00, add(b01, b11, split_index, -1)));
        vector<vector<int>> p2(strassen_multiplication(add(a00, a01, split_index), b11));
        vector<vector<int>> p3(strassen_multiplication(add(a10, a11, split_index), b00));
        vector<vector<int>> p4(strassen_multiplication(a11, add(b10, b00, split_index, -1)));
        vector<vector<int>> p5(strassen_multiplication(add(a00, a11, split_index),add(b00, b11, split_index)));
        vector<vector<int>> p6(strassen_multiplication(add(a01, a11, split_index, -1),add(b10, b11, split_index)));
        vector<vector<int>> p7(strassen_multiplication(add(a00, a10, split_index, -1),add(b00, b01, split_index)));

        // calculating the result
        vector<vector<int> > result_00(add(add(add(p5, p4, split_index), p6, split_index), p2, split_index, -1));
        vector<vector<int> > result_01(add(p1, p2, split_index));
        vector<vector<int> > result_10(add(p3, p4, split_index));
        vector<vector<int> > result_11(add(add(add(p5, p1, split_index), p3, split_index, -1), p7, split_index, -1));

        // calulating and storing the result
        // inside matrix
        for (auto i = 0; i < split_index; i++){
            for (auto j = 0; j < split_index; j++) {
                result[i][j] = result_00[i][j];
                result[i][j + split_index] = result_01[i][j];
                result[split_index + i][j] = result_10[i][j];
                result[i + split_index][j + split_index] = result_11[i][j];
            }
        }

        // clearing all the arrays
        a00.clear();  a01.clear();  a10.clear();  a11.clear();
        b00.clear();  b01.clear();  b10.clear();  b11.clear();
        p1.clear(); p2.clear(); p3.clear(); p4.clear(); p5.clear(); p6.clear(); p7.clear();
        result_00.clear();  result_01.clear();  result_10.clear();  result_11.clear();
    }
    return result;
}

int main() 
{
  // Input Matrix A
    vector<vector<int>> A = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}};
    // Input Matrix B
  vector<vector<int>> B = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}};
  // Getting the result
    vector<vector<int> > result(strassen_multiplication(A, B));
  // Printing the result
    print(result);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, sir. yes, the code is not mine I am trying to implement it on my own so while referring to online content I came across the code and got stuck with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a moment to read the `add` function, you will discover the fourth parameter is named `multiplier` and has a default value of 1. It is a good name for a variable, because it describes clearly what it will be used for.

Continuing to read the function, you will see that `multiplier` is used to scale `B` during addition. Logically, that means if you pass `-1` as a multiplier, then the operation becomes a *subtraction* instead of an *addition*.

What seems strange to me is that you say you are programming this. One would expect that means the code is yours. So you should understand what it does and why. I guess the code is not yours.

You could make the code a bit clearer if you do this:

```
// Add two matrices and return the result
vector<vector<int>> add_scaled(
    vector<vector<int>> A,
    const vector<vector<int>>& B,
    int split_index,
    int multiplier)
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < split_index; i++)
        for (auto j = 0; j < split_index; j++)
            A[i][j] = A[i][j] + (multiplier * B[i][j]);
    return A;
}

vector<vector<int>> add(
    vector<vector<int>> A,
    const vector<vector<int>>& B,
    int split_index)
{
    return add_scaled(A, B, split_index, 1);
}

vector<vector<int>> subtract(
    vector<vector<int>> A,
    const vector<vector<int>>& B,
    int split_index)
{
    return add_scaled(A, B, split_index, -1);
}
```

This turns your original `add` function into `add_scaled`, and creates two simpler functions `add` and `subtract` which do not do any scaling. Then you have:

```
vector<vector<int>> p1(strassen_multiplication(a00, subtract(b01, b11, split_index)));
vector<vector<int>> p2(strassen_multiplication(add(a00, a01, split_index), b11));
vector<vector<int>> p3(strassen_multiplication(add(a10, a11, split_index), b00));
vector<vector<int>> p4(strassen_multiplication(a11, subtract(b10, b00, split_index)));
// etc...
```

Comment: Another way to rework this might be to overload the add() function without the last parameter and avoid the default value. Refer to your style guide (if any) for what way to prefer :)

Comment: thank you sir for your response, yes the code is not mine, i am try to implement on my own so while searching for reference online i came across it and stuck with the add function.